# Any way to drive 2 monitors from a 2008 Mac mini?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dvi, vga, mac-mini

Is there any way that I can use two monitors (both DVI/VGA capable) from a Mac Mini with a single DVI port?

---

Any free solutions?

Comment: what is the purpose?

Comment: @bert - Not sure I understand... hmmm... to use both monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen one myself, but Matrox make something called a "DualHead2Go" which is intended to enable "dual-display capabilities to notebooks or desktops that lack such functionality due to insufficient amount of outputs" (which seems to describe your situation exactly).  More [here](http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/mobile/display/20051108205755.html) and [here](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a USB to DVI or USB to VGA adapter... No idea how well they work or if they work on the mini though.

Comment: Yup some exist supporting the mac e.g http://www.macnn.com/articles/08/08/28/see2.xtreme.video.card/